# How to connect to remote db having firewall protection

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-access, firewall, azure-web-app-service

I have a mysql db which is residing in ec2 instance and is protected by a firewall. I have a web application which is deployed in azure and have to access this remote db. For this I have to whitelist web app's IP address but I 
am facing problem while upscaling my application because every time I upscale,
I need to whitelist a new set of IP address and vice-versa when downscaling.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I have is to put small instance upfront of the DB server in AWS that will listen to the the same DB port as your DB server, Look at haproxy with TCP port balancing to DB server and with client certificate validation.
So your web server will connect to this haproxy server and present client certificate
to haproxy server. If it is valid it will pass through. In this case you can open that secure port quite wide open or limit it to CIDRs that belongs to Azure.

Look at this article:
http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/client-certificate-authentication-with-haproxy/

Answer (score 0):

One can enable [Azure LoadBalancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-standard-manage-portal) to autoscale your webtier instances. This Load Balancer can be assigned a static Public IP address which can then be whitelisted on AWS side to access your EC2 DB instance.

Alternatively,  [Azure AppServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips) provide auto-scaling and high availability without the need of LoadBalancer and allow its IP address or the range to be whitelisted.